# Transform into decimal preventing trimming 0s

Tags: sas

I'm in a situation like the one reported here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/New-SAS-User/Transform-integer-into-decimal/m-p/918994#M41156

Suppose, to have the following data (all numeric, not character):

> ```
> data have;
> input Hosp1 Hosp2 ;
> cards;
> 71515   42731
> 48041 5761
> 4329    481
> 85201  42731
> 85220   5119
> 4280  40211
> 2510   4280
> 39   22
> ;
> run;
> ```

What I would like is the following output:

[image]

If I try using this code (as from yabwon):

> ```
> data want;
> set have;
> array H hosp1 hosp2;
> do over H;
>   H = H/(10**max(0,ceil(log10(H))-3)); 
>  end;
>  format hosp1 hosp2 best.;
>  run;
> ```

The output is as follows:

[image]

In other words 4280 becomes 428 but instead I would like 428.0 The same for 2510. Is there a way to prevent it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your input and your desired output are the same, neither have any decimal places.  So what is it you want to do?  If you are trying to move the decimal place please explain how you know where to place it.

Comment: Hi Tom, simply I would like that the last 0 when there, does not disappear. The code does the job except when numbers have the last number = 0

Comment: Not sure what you mean about zeros disappearing. Remember that if you have a NUMBER (instead of CHARACTER string) then leading zeros before the decimal point and trailing zeros after the decimal point are meaningless.

Comment: Are you working with lab equipment that has important significant digit features ? If so, you will likely need to also store the number of significant digits of a value along with the 'number'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the number that 428 represents and the number that 428.0 represents.

It trailing zeros after the decimal point are meaningful then you need to store the value as a character string.  (Note no need to bother with using ARRAYs for just two variables.)

```
data want;
  set have;
  length chosp1 chosp2 $8 ;
  chosp1 = put(hosp1,7.-L);
  chosp1 = substr(chosp1,1,3)||'.'||substr(chosp1,4);
  chosp2 = put(hosp2,7.-L);
  chosp2 = substr(chosp2,1,3)||'.'||substr(chosp2,4);
run;
```

Comment: No idea if this is why, but the one place that is not true is when considering precision in scientific work; 428.0 is different from 428 in that 428.0 shows it is more precisely measured.

Comment: @Joe You are making an assumption that using the string `428.0` means you consider the value to have 4 significant digits.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm assuming (otherwise, as you say, why would it matter - but the question wouldn't really make sense then.)

Comment: @Joe the problem is that no common languages track the number of significant digits, so once it leaves the string domain you're lost.  It becomes impossible to do any meaningful arithmetic.

Comment: @MarkRansom SAS itself does have this capability (in DS2); many languages do. It's called the 'decimal' type typically.  Stores things exactly as above really - an integer, and a precision marker.

Comment: @Joe I think we'll have to disagree on the definition of "many" but I see your point.  I'm ignorant of SAS specifically so that's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `PICTURE` format.

Example:

```
proc format;
  picture mypic 
    10000-99999 = '999.99' (mult=1)
     1000- 9999 = '999.9'  (mult=1)
      100-  999 = '99.9'   (mult=1)
/*       10-   99 = '9.9'    (mult=1)*/
  ;
run;


data have;
input Hosp1 Hosp2 ;
format hosp1-hosp2 mypic.;
put hosp1 hosp2 ;
cards;
71515   42731
48041 5761
4329    481
85201  42731
85220   5119
4280  40211
2510   4280
39   22
;
run;
```

Logs

```
715.15 427.31
480.41 576.1
432.9 48.1
852.01 427.31
852.20 511.9
428.0 402.11
251.0 428.0
39 22
```

Comment: This doesn't match the (impossible to really match!) results, unfortunately (look at 481).

Comment: @Joe are you sure it's impossible?  It seems like a simple algorithm, while the number is greater than 1000 divide it by 10.  Keep track of the number of divisions so you know how many decimal places to display.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP sample desired output did not pass a clarity check.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hmm, you're right, missed that pattern somehow...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a *character variable*, not a numeric variable; that's the only thing that can perfectly match what you are asking for.

The way to handle this is to keep the true numeric, then to store the width and decimal length in other fields; then use the `put` function with those variables to store the final result in a character field.

SAS numerics are floating point decimals, not Decimal type.

The other option is to use DS2, which *does* have a Decimal type.

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/ds2pg/n0v130wmh3hmuzn1t7y5y4pgxa69.htm

> DECIMAL|NUMERIC( p, s)
>
> > stores a signed, exact, fixed-point decimal number, with user-specified precision and scale. The precision and scale determines the position of the decimal point. The precision is the maximum number of digits that can be stored to the left and right of the decimal point, with a range of 1 to 52. The scale is the maximum number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point. Scale must be less than or equal to the precision. For example, decimal(9,2) stores decimal numbers up to nine digits, with a two-digit fixed-point fractional portion, such as 1234567.89.